# Simplifying a summation with binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Simplify the sum

$$
f(k,q)=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{2i}{i+q}\binom{2k-2i}{k-i}
$$

where $k,q$ are given integers satisfying $0<q\le k$.

I tried to simplify it combinatorially. For a lattice path $p$ using steps (1,1) and (1,-1) and starts from the origin, define $g_q(p)$ to be the number of intersections between $p$ and the line $y=2q$. One can notice that $f(k,q)$ calculates the sum $g_q(p)$ for all lattice paths from the origin to (2k,2q). If we enumerate the rightmost intersection between the path and the line $y=2q$, and denote its $x$ position by $2t$, then we have

$$
f(k,q)=\sum_{t=0}^k\left(\binom{2t}{t+q}-2\binom{2t-1}{t+q}\right)4^{k-t}
$$

However this does not make the problem easier. How should I proceed? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just as a guide: When $q=0,$ this is well known to be $4^k.$

Comment: Isn’t $g_k(p)=1$ for any $p$?

Comment: No I think. And also there's a typo, I mean $g_q(p)$ instead of $g_k(p)$

Comment: It should be $1$, as a path that monotonically goes to the right should cross a vertical line at exactly one point.

Comment: Oops, there was another typo. I mean the line $y=2q$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing we seek to simplify

$$\sum_{j=0}^k {2j\choose j+q} {2k-2j\choose k-j}.$$

where $0\le q\le k.$ This is

$$[z^k] (1+z)^{2k} 
\sum_{j=0}^k {2j\choose j+q} \frac{z^j}{(1+z)^{2j}}.$$

Here the coefficient extractor enforces the upper limit of the sum
and we find

$$[z^k] (1+z)^{2k} 
\sum_{j\ge 0} {2j\choose j+q} \frac{z^j}{(1+z)^{2j}}.$$

At this point we see that we will require residues and complex
integration and continue with

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2k}}{z^{k+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{q+1}}
\sum_{j\ge 0} \frac{(1+w)^{2j}}{w^j} \frac{z^j}{(1+z)^{2j}}
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2k}}{z^{k+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{q+1}}
\frac{1}{1-z(1+w)^2/w/(1+z)^2}
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2k+2}}{z^{k+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{q}}
\frac{1}{w(1+z)^2-z(1+w)^2}
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2k+2}}{z^{k+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{q}}
\frac{1}{(w-z)(1-wz)}
\; dw \; dz.$$

For    the   geometric    series    to   converge    we   must    have
$|z(1+w)^2/w/(1+z)^2| \lt  1$ or  $|z/(1+z)^2| \lt  |w/(1+w)^2|.$ This
requires  $\varepsilon/(1-\varepsilon)^2 \lt  \gamma/(1+\gamma)^2.$ We
will also require  $w=z$ to be inside  the contour for $w$  so we need
$\varepsilon \lt \gamma.$ With $\varepsilon  \ll 1$ and $\gamma \ll 1$
we may take $\varepsilon = \gamma^2$ for the latter inquality. We then
get    for     the    inquality    from    the     geometric    series
$\gamma^2/(1-\gamma^2)^2  \lt \gamma  / (1+\gamma)^2$  or $\gamma  \lt
(1-\gamma^2)^2/(1+\gamma)^2$ or $\gamma  \lt (1-\gamma)^2.$ This holds
for $\gamma\lt 1-1/\varphi$ with $\varphi$ the golden mean.

Now  we have the  pole at  zero and the  one at $w=z$  inside the
contour in $w$.  This means we can evaluate the  integral by using the
fact that  residues sum to zero,  taking minus the residue  at $w=1/z$
and  minus the  residue  at  infinity, which  is  zero by  inspection,
however.  (The pole  at  $w=1/z$ has  modulus  $1/\varepsilon$ and  is
outside the contour.)  Computing minus the residue at $w=1/z$ we write

$$- \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2k+2}}{z^{k+2}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{q}}
\frac{1}{(w-z)(w-1/z)}
\; dw \; dz.$$

With the sign change we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2k+2}}{z^{k+2}} 
z^q \frac{1}{1/z-z} \; dz
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2k+2}}{z^{k-q+1}} 
\frac{1}{1-z^2} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2k+1}}{z^{k-q+1}} 
\frac{1}{1-z} \; dz.$$

This is zero when $q\gt k$ and otherwise

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-q} {2k+1\choose j}
= \sum_{j=0}^k {2k+1\choose j}
- \sum_{j=k-q+1}^k {2k+1\choose j}$$

or alternatively

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
4^k - \sum_{j=k-q+1}^k {2k+1\choose j}}$$

which is a closed  form term plus a sum of $q$  terms. E.g. with $q=0$
we obtain $4^k$ and with $q=1,$ $4^k - {2k+1\choose k}$.  For $q=2$ we
have $4^k - {2k+1\choose k-1} - {2k+1\choose k}$ and so on.

Comment: Thank you! But the procedure is somehow beyond my level and might not be the best proof to the identity. Since the result turns out to be fairly neat, I'm considering is there's a simpler combinatorial proof to this. But again I'm greatly appreciated for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got a combinatorial method for this problem. Below "path" means lattice path using steps $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ and starting from the origin $(0,0)$. And I'll list some well-known formulas that might be used in the proof:

1. Number of paths ending at $(n,k)$ (denoted by $N(n,k)$): $[(n+k)\text{ is even}]\binom{n}{(n+k)/2}$
2. Number of paths ending at $(n,q)$ and touch the line $y=r$ at least once ($q<r$) (Hint: Reflection Principle): $N(n,2r-q)$
3. Number of paths consisting of $n$ steps and touch the line $y=r$ at least once (Hint: sum up formula 2): $N(n, r)+2\sum_{i=r+1}^nN(n,i)$
4. Number of paths consisting of $n$ steps and never go below the $x$ axis ($y=0$) (Hint: sum up formula 3): $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$

Let's consider the combinatorial meaning of the summation. One can notice that $f(k,q)$ counts all the paths consisting of $2k+1$ steps whose final $y$ coordinate is $2q+1$ or more: we enumerate the rightmost intersection between the path and the line $y=2q$, and denote its $x$ coordinate by $2t$ (clearly it must be even). So the left part has $N(2t,2q)=\binom{2t}{t+q}$ possibilities, and the right part, since it cannot go below $y=2q+1$ except for the first step ($(2t,2q)$ is already the rightmost intersection), we'll have $\binom{2k+1-2i-1}{(2k+1-2i-1)/2}=\binom{2k-2i}{k-i}$ possibilities (formula 4).

And according to formula 1, we have another form for the quantity, that is to say

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(k,q)&=\sum_{i=2q+1}^{2k+1}N(2k+1,i)\\
&=\sum_{i=q}^k\binom{2k+1}{k+i+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-q}\binom{2k+1}i
\end{aligned}
$$

This yields the same result as Marko Riedel's answer. Sorry for my verbose description and poor English, I tried my best to make it clear for everyone. Feel free to comment if you think I have typo and mistake.

Comment: Very nice! Here is a way of rephrasing your argument. $\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{2i}{i+q}\binom{2(k-i)}{k-i}$ counts paths of length $2k+1$ whose final $y$-coordinate is $2q+1$ or more; $\binom{2i}{i+q}$ counts the ways to reach $y=2q$ fro the first time, and $\binom{2(k-i)}{k-i}$ counts the paths which never go below $y=2q$. On the other hand, the number of paths which end at $(2k+1,2q+1)$ is obviously, by (1), $\sum_{i=0}^{k-q} \binom{2k+1}{i}$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you for your advice! By the way, I think $\binom{2i}{i+q}$ counts the way to reach $y=2q$ for the last time indeed.

Answer (score 0):

hint

Since $q$ and $i$ are non negative, the first binomial is null unless $q+i \le 2i$, i.e. $q \le i$, i.e. the sum actually starts from $q$.
Then change the index from $i$ to $j=k-i$.
At this stage express the binomials through the gamma function, and apply the duplication formula for gamma ...